# Números elevados al cubo java

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio que me pide sacar los números del 1 al 1000 con la siguiente propiedad: Por ejemplo, el número 17 si lo elevamos al cubo da 4913, y sumando las cifras del resultado (4+9+1+3) nos da el mismo número, 17. El código que tengo de momento es este:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int suma = 0;
        String[] div = new String[4];
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        String num = Integer.toString(i);
        div = num.split("");
        String vid1 = div[i];
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(vid1);
        suma = suma + num1;
        if (suma == i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        }
    }
```

Lo que he hecho es que el número del bucle se pase a String para hacer la división con split, y después pasar lo a int para hacer las operaciones, pero me da el error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Si hay alguna forma más sencilla de hacer el ejercicio me gustaría saberla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres, con este código se puede resolver.

1. Abriremos un bucle con números del 1 al 1000.
2. Dentro del bucle, por cada número, llamaremos al método `calcularPotencia`, el cual se valdrá de `Math.pow` para calcular el cubo de cada número. Para hacer ese método más flexible, he dejado la opción de pasarle en parámetro la potencia que se quiere calcular, ya que `pow` sirve para calcular cualquier potencia, no sólo la 3.
3. Dentro de `calcularPotencia`, pasaremos el valor obtenido a otro método `sumarDigitos` el cual, convertirá el valor de la potencia a entero, ya que el resultado de cualquier cálculo de potencia es siempre un `double`. Y lo que haremos será, dentro de un ciclo `while` obtener cada cifra por separado de una forma estratégica: haciendo esta operación `intPotencia % 10`. Y al mismo tiempo iremos acumulando cada valor en `intSuma`. Al final comparamos si `intSuma` es igual a `intValor` y de ser así, imprimimos un mensaje.

Como podrás apreciar, los valores se manejan de una manera limpia, sin tener que recurrir a conversiones que podrían ser problemáticas y costosas a nivel de código. La única conversión de datos que se hace es esta:

```
int intPotencia = (int) dblPotencia;
```

por lo ya explicado más arriba en el punto 3.

Aquí va el código:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            calcularPotencia(i, 3);
        }

    }

    public static void calcularPotencia(int intValor, int intPotencia) {

        double dblPotencia = Math.pow(intValor, intPotencia);
        sumarDigitos(dblPotencia, intValor);

    }

    public static void sumarDigitos(double dblPotencia, int intValor) {

        int intPotencia = (int) dblPotencia;
        int intSuma = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (intPotencia > 0) {
            intSuma = intSuma + intPotencia % 10;
            sb.append(intPotencia % 10);
            sb.append("+");
            intPotencia = intPotencia / 10;
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

        if (intValor == intSuma) {
        System.out.println("Valor: \t" + intValor + " \tSumas por cada dígito: \t" + sb.toString() + "=" + intValor + " \tPotencia 3 calculada:" + dblPotencia);
        }
    }

}
```

---

#### Resultado:

```
Valor:  1   Sumas por cada dígito:  1=1             Potencia 3 calculada:1.0
Valor:  8   Sumas por cada dígito:  2+1+5=8         Potencia 3 calculada:512.0
Valor:  17  Sumas por cada dígito:  3+1+9+4=17      Potencia 3 calculada:4913.0
Valor:  18  Sumas por cada dígito:  2+3+8+5=18      Potencia 3 calculada:5832.0
Valor:  26  Sumas por cada dígito:  6+7+5+7+1=26    Potencia 3 calculada:17576.0
Valor:  27  Sumas por cada dígito:  3+8+6+9+1=27    Potencia 3 calculada:19683.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: El resultado es el correcto, pero podrías explicarme para qué se utiliza el StringBuilder y .append? Es algo nuevo que todavía no he visto

Comment: Se usa para fabricar (build)  cadenas (string). No es parte importante del código, lo usé sólo para imprimir cada suma que se iba haciendo, por ejemplo `3+1+9+4`.  `append` se usa para cada vez que quieres agregar algo a la cadena que se va construyendo (concatenación de cadenas). Se puede hacer como habitualmente: `"cadena1" + "cadena2" + "cadena n"`, sólo que por lo general, se recomienda el uso de `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int divm;
    for(int i=1; i<=1000;i++)
    {  

        int suma=0; 
        int aux=(int) Math.pow(i,3);
        while(aux!=0)
        {  
            divm=aux%10;
            aux/=10;
            suma+=divm;

        }

        if(suma==i) {
            System.out.println("numero: "+i+" elevado al cubo: "+(int)Math.pow(i,3)+" la suma es igual a: "+suma);  

        }
    }
}
```

De esta manera creo que es una solución mas rápida ya que en el while ejecuta la suma de los dígitos del valor i elevado al cubo, luego la suma se compara con el valor del numero i, coloco auxiliar porque en cada iteracion se renueva el valor del cubo del numero i.